# Moderation Tools - Section headers shift even when content is blank

Tags: bug, design

In the **Moderation Tools** section, there are many sections such as "Most commented", "Highest voted", "Recently protected", etc.

If a section is empty (which is usually the case for [PPCG's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) "Recently protected" section), clicking on the section header will toggle it between being farther left and a bit closer to the right. This seems to be be because all of the section headers are configured to toggle their position when clicked in order to make way for the drop-down arrow which is wider than it is tall when pointing down.

The drop-down arrow does not show up for empty sections, so it seems there is a way to determine if a section is empty, but the section header still shifts around. While this does not impact functionality, it looks really awkward. Is there any way to fix this?